# I cant make my project to compile with Random Class - Error on debug [util.c:840]

Tags: java, constructor

I need help on this exercise which asks me to create a random method on the constructor, but it's not working, if I click run, it just does nothing, and if a try to debug I get this error on the console:

```
ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [util.c:840]
```

Persona :

```
     public class Persona {

        private String nombre;
        private String dni; 
        public Persona(String nombre, String dni) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            generaDni();
                }

        public void generaDni(){

            Random generadorAleatorios = new Random();

                    int numeroAleatorio = generadorAleatorios.nextInt()/1000000000;

                dni= String.valueOf(numeroAleatorio);

                }

        public String toString() {
            return "Nombre= " + nombre +", DNI "+dni;
        }
}
```

Uso_Persona :

```
    public class Uso_Persona {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Persona p1= new Persona("Brenda Conzi", "dni");

        p1.generaDni();;

        p1.toString();
        }
   }
```

Comment: You need to write code that actually does something visible if you want to observe results. Such as `System.out.println(p1);`.

Comment: Calling `p1.toString()` just converts it to a String, but if you don't print it, nothing appears to happen.  If your debug produces this error it appears your environment is not setup correctly.